# How to attach a detail sheet as pdf or excel from a pivot table using Google App Scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a student attendance system. It has a count value of attendance per student in the COUNT column of a pivot table coming from TempDataSet tab. My expectation can be achieved through either of the two ways:

> Process 01: Manually when I click on any cell of the Count column of a pivot table in the Dashboard, it produces a details of attendance of
> that student where data is coming from 'TempDataSet' like which days s/he attended a
> class. Then sheet name is the details-abc@gmail.com. Then I can send
> the details sheet as pdf to the student's email address manually. Now the whole process can be done automatically using Google App Scripts?
>
> OR Process 02: Split the TempDataSet (same pattern of the attached image) tab based on student email IDs and send to the students as attachment by email individually. However, I have 50-60 students in a class, so all should be done by a single click from the Dashboard, which is working fine now but the issues is it is sending the whole TempDataSet tab to all students instead of splitting the TempDataSet info and sending each student specific info.

The following codes are working fine for a single sheet tab download and email as excel attachment (all students attendance info in a single sheet to all students:

```
function autoEmailing(){
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssID = sss.getId();
  var sheetName = sss.getName(); 
  var sheet = sss.getSheetByName("TempDataSet");
  var sheet1 = sss.insertSheet('TempDataSet_temp');
  sheet.getDataRange().copyTo(sheet1.getActiveRange(), 
  SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  sheet.getDataRange().copyTo(sheet1.getActiveRange(), 
  SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);  

  var shID = sheet1.getSheetId().toString();
  sheet1.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() -1, 
  sheet.getLastColumn()).sort({column: 3, ascending: true}); 
  var columns_delete = [7,5,4,2];
  columns_delete.forEach(col=>sheet1.deleteColumn(col));
 
  var subject = 'Your Attendance Record at BDU';
  var body = 'Dear Student,'+ '\n\n' + 'Greetings! Please find the attendance record attached for your reference.' + '\n\n' + 'Thank you.';
  
  var requestData = {"method": "GET", "headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};  
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ ssID + "/export?format=xlsx&id="+ssID+"&gid="+shID;

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , requestData);  
  var contents = result.getContent();
  sss.deleteSheet(sss.getSheetByName('TempDataSet_temp'));   
  
  var sheet2 = sss.getSheetByName('StudentList');  
  var data = sheet2.getLastRow();
  var students = [];
  var students = sheet2.getRange(2, 6, data).getValues(); 
  //MailApp.sendEmail(students.toString(), subject ,body, {attachments:[{fileName:sheetName+".xlsx", content:contents, mimeType:"MICROSOFT_EXCEL"}]});
  
  for (var i=0; i<students.length; i++){ // you are looping through rows and selecting the 1st and only column index
    if (students[i][0] !== ''){           
      MailApp.sendEmail(students[i][0].toString(), subject ,body, {attachments:[{fileName:sheetName+".xlsx", content:contents, mimeType:"MICROSOFT_EXCEL"}]}); 
    } 
  }
```

}
[image: Student Individual Attendance Sheet for Email]

Comment: Please describe how is this process done:
>Manually when I click on it, it produces a details of attendance of that student like which days s/he attended a class.

Comment: When I double click on any of the values on Column2 (COUNT), it produces a detail attendance sheet of that student. For example, at the attached image if you click on B13 cell which has a value 99, it will produce details of the 99 attendance s/he did. Please consider the sheet as a pivot table and generated details sheet is at the 2nd Tab.

Comment: I see, please share an example sheet with the input and update your question with the desired output. This will allow us to help you better.

Comment: @Alessandro, I updated my post as per your suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean to send `1802001@email.com` only the row 13 in this case? Or the content of the `Detail30-1802001@email.com` Sheet (if this is the case please share how to obtain the `Detail-sheet`)?

Comment: The content of the Detail30-1802001@email.com to 1802001@email.com and it should be done for all students at time. Please read Process 01 or Process 02 in the above post which explains how to get the detail sheet.

Comment: I would like to propose a third pattern. We can create a checkbox column next to the students. When you click on this checkbox an email will be sent to the student of that row together with the relevant email. Would you like a solution like that ?

Comment: @Marios, great idea but the attachment should be the students' specific attendance information like the attached image. Another idea is, students are viewers in the system so if we make the count value for each student as a hyperlink, will it show details attendance info by the students click as a viewer? If it is possible we do not even need to send emails!!

Comment: @LitonEDU the issue with the patterns you are defined is that you can not trigger a function with a **click**. So you can only trigger via edit, or time trigger, or button trigger etc.

Comment: @Marios are you saying to create checkbox at the pivot table in the Dashboard tab where students email, COUNT, percentage and marks are there as separate columns? If so, then when each checkboxes are ticked, then corresponding email will go and the detail attendance info of that student will be enclosed at excel attachment. Am I right?

Comment: @LitonEDU exactly!

Comment: Great idea, please go ahead. Do you need to have access the Google Sheets?

Comment: @LitonEDU I think no, I will do it in 4-5 hours like yesterday.

Comment: @Marios it is better for us to include 'FROM' in the MailApp.sendEmail() - the email address from which the mail is sent. In my case it is the active user that I consider from Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() as there are other teachers also taking attendance. Please consider it to your solution as well. Thanks

Comment: @Marios are you ok? Is there any update of the pattern you mentioned? There is one solution posted here but it is not working though it is a good way to solve this issue.

Comment: @LitonEDU I decided to move forward with an iterative approach since I know that you already have an onEdit trigger installed and it will interfere with the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

- The following script iterates over the pivot table (**Dashboard**) and
  for each student email it filters the relevant data, for that
  particular student, from the **TempDataSet** sheet and copies it to a
  temporary sheet named `temp_sh`. Finally, the latter gets emailed as
  an excel file to the particular student.
- It is important to mention that `Spreadsheet.flush()` is really necessary in this scenario because the script constantly creates and deletes a temporary sheet and therefore there are pending changes that need to be made in each iteration.

---

### Solution:

```
function emailSender(){

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const sh_db = ss.getSheetByName('Dashboard');
const sh_tds = ss.getSheetByName('TempDataSet');

const u_emails = sh_db.getRange('A13:A57').getValues().flat(); // adjust this to your specific range
const data = sh_tds.getRange('A1:G'+sh_tds.getLastRow()).getValues();

const subject = 'Your Attendance Record at BDU';
const body = 'Dear Student,'+ '\n\n' + 'Greetings! Please find the attendance record attached for your reference.' + '\n\n' + 'Thank you.';
const from = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
const requestData = {"method": "GET", "headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}}; 
const ssID = ss.getId();

u_emails.forEach(e=>{

  var temp_data = data.filter( row => {
    return (row[2] == e || row[2] == 'Umail'); 
  });
  
  var temp_sh = ss.insertSheet('temp_sheet');
  temp_sh.getRange(1,1,temp_data.length,temp_data[0].length).setValues(temp_data);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var shID = temp_sh.getSheetId();
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ ssID + "/export?format=xlsx&id="+ ssID +"&gid="+shID;
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , requestData);  
  var contents = result.getContent();
  ss.deleteSheet(temp_sh);
  
  GmailApp.sendEmail(e, subject ,body, {from: from, attachments:[{fileName:"YourAttendaceRecord.xlsx", content:contents, mimeType:"MICROSOFT_EXCEL"}]});

});

}
```

Comment: Initially it was not working after sending 5-6 emails with attachment. Then I have put a line [Utilities.sleep(10000)] before this line of code: var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , requestData); and now it is working fine though it is time consuming. I reduced the sleeping time to 5 sec but again it failed. Probably 10 sec is better but I saw total execution time is 551 sec in the trigger. Is it Ok?

Comment: My range for emails is always starting on A13 cell (fixed) at the Dashboard but the end cell changes based on the selection. So it may be A57, or A67 or A90. Actually it starts from A13 cell and then go downwards until the cell (e.g A57, A67 or any) appears blank in the same column. So it is better if it can be defined dynamically. Could you please update. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

You can't obtain the detail with the "double-click" fashon automatically. So what about this workaround?

### Building the detail via Apps Script

Since you are filtering by the email addresses it's easy to get a filtered detail report based on your source data. First you will filter the data using the pivot table email addresses column and then you will build a temporary sheet with the filtered rows and columns.

Here is an example of how this script would work:

```js
function sendEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pivot = ss.getActiveSheet(); // You will start the script while in the Pivot Table Dashboard
  var from = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); // Gets the email address of the active user executing the script
  var db = ss.getSheetByName("Database"); // Pivot table source data sheet
  var emails = pivot.getRange("A2:A").getValues(); // Pivot table column with email addresses
  emails.forEach(email => {
             var filteredRows = db.getDataRange().getValues().filter(row => row[6] == email[0]); // Filters the database with each email address
             var temp = ss.insertSheet("TempDataSet_temp"); // Creates the temporary sheet
             temp.appendRow(["Timestamp","StudentID-Name","Umail", "..."]); // Fills the header of the report
             filteredRows.forEach(row => temp.appendRow(row)); // Appends the filtered rows to the temporary Sheet

             var subject = 'Your Attendance Record at BDU';
             var body = 'Dear Student,'+ '\n\n' + 'Greetings! Please find the attendance record attached for your reference.' + '\n\n' + 'Thank you.';
  
             var requestData = {"method": "GET", "headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};  
             var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ ss.getId() + "/export?format=xlsx&id="+ss.getId()+"&gid="+temp.getSheetId();
  
             var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , requestData);  
             var contents = result.getContent();
             ss.deleteSheet(temp); // Once the Spreadsheet is exported I will delete the temporary sheet for future operations
             
             MailApp.sendEmail(email[0], subject ,body, {from: from, attachments:[{fileName:"YourAttendaceRecord.xlsx", content:contents, mimeType:"MICROSOFT_EXCEL"}]}); // Send the emails to the correct recipient and his/her relative report

  });
}
```

### References

[getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)

[appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents)

[Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: it is partially working. 1st 6 emails were sent out of 50 with attachment with  only correct column header and all other rows are empty. I saw TempDataSet_temp is created 6 times in the status bar and deleted and then it is stuck. I checked the trigger executions and it shows, "Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id 1uIs3NQUcNrp_5kdDZ_fGxGTmRI2CMaEg_W_0aQbLFhc.
    at [unknown function](classattendance:493:47)
    at [unknown function](classattendance:493:27)
    at sendEmails(classattendance:489:10)
    at classAttendance(classattendance:13:7)"

Comment: @Alessandro In the MailApp.sendEmail() it is showing that 'from' is an invalid argument for editors (except the owner). So editors can't send email from their email address.