# Showing errors, the data validation rule has more items than the limit of 500. Use the list from a range criteria instead

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The following codes showing errors due to limit of 500. I tried to solve it and reviewed many docs but failed. Is there any way to solve it?

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();  
  var dashboard = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
  var wsOptions = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Master");
  var options = wsOptions.getRange(2, 1, wsOptions.getLastRow()-1,6).getDisplayValues();
  
  function onEdit(e){

    var as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var val = e.range.getValue();
    var val_not = e.range.getA1Notation();
    
    if (val_not =='F5' && as.getName() == "Dashboard"){
    
    if(val === "All"){
       dashboard.getRange('G5').setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
       dashboard.getRange('G5').clearDataValidations();      
    }
    else{
      var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){return o[5] === val});
      var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){return o[0]}).sort().reverse();
      
      var cell = dashboard.getRange('G5');
      var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(listToApply).setAllowInvalid(false).build();

      cell.clearContent();
      cell.clearDataValidations();
      cell.setDataValidation(rule);            
    }      
  } 
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation:**

As the error suggests:

> The data validation rule has more items than the limit of 500. Use the
> ‘List from a range’ criteria instead.

you should use [requireValueInRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder).

In order to use the latter, you need to define a **range** of data validation items. In the following approach, I create a range of these items `opt_range` and I use that as an argument for the `requireValueInRange()` function.

**Solution 1:**

```
function onEdit(e){      
  var as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var val = e.range.getValue();
  var val_not = e.range.getA1Notation(); 
  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();  
  var dashboard = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
  var wsOptions = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Master");
  var options = wsOptions.getRange(2, 1, wsOptions.getLastRow()-1,6).getDisplayValues();
  
    
  if (val_not =='F5' && as.getName() == "Dashboard"){
    
      if(val === "All"){
        dashboard.getRange('G5').setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
        dashboard.getRange('G5').clearDataValidations();      
      }
      else{
        var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){return o[5] === val});
        var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){return o[0]}).sort().reverse();
        var listToApply2D = listToApply.map(ta=>[ta]);       
        var jSize = wsOptions.getRange('J:J').getValues().filter(String).length;
 
        if (jSize>0){ wsOptions.getRange(1,10,jSize,1).clearContent()};
        wsOptions.getRange(1,10,listToApply2D.length,listToApply2D[0].length).setValues(listToApply2D);
        var opt_range = wsOptions.getRange(1,10,listToApply2D.length,listToApply2D[0].length);        
        var cell = dashboard.getRange('G5');
        var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(opt_range).build();

        cell.clearContent();
        cell.clearDataValidations();
        cell.setDataValidation(rule);            
      }      
    } 
  }
```

**Solution 2 (recommended):**

Assuming you don't have 500 unique items in the list, you can still use the code you posted, but take the unique list of the items:

```
  function onEdit(e){

    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();  
    var dashboard = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
    var wsOptions = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Master");
    var options = wsOptions.getRange(2, 1, wsOptions.getLastRow()-1,6).getDisplayValues();

    var as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var val = e.range.getValue();
    var val_not = e.range.getA1Notation();
    
    
    if (val_not =='F5' && as.getName() == "Dashboard"){
    
    if(val === "All"){
       dashboard.getRange('G5').setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
       dashboard.getRange('G5').clearDataValidations();      
    }
    else{
      var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){return o[5] === val});
      var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){return o[0]}).sort().reverse();
      var uniqueList = listToApply.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i); // <= New code
      
      var cell = dashboard.getRange('G5');
      var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(uniqueList).setAllowInvalid(false).build();

      cell.clearContent();
      cell.clearDataValidations();
      cell.setDataValidation(rule);            
    }      
  } 
  }
```

Comment: Sorry to say, it is not working. Could you please check at the given sheet link. Thanks

Comment: @TamjidTaha sorry try again. I already updated the code in the file. Keep in mind, the code can only be executed by the person that has access to the master sheet. I assume you do have access. Let me know otherwise.

Comment: It is a solution but I can't use it as it takes long time to load and when I open the spreadsheet 1st time, often it does not work. Your previous solution was the best one but due to limit of 500, it has no value. Is there any other way to make it really fast like your previous solution?

Comment: Can we limit this line for 1st 500 entries like var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){return o[0]}).sort.reverse(); I do not need all dates for each subject instead if I can get 6-10 latest dates is fine. So how we can do that?

Comment: @TamjidTaha can you try the second solution in my updated answer? It should be very fast and with no errors :)

Comment: What an excellent solution it is! Really fast and exactly what I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: @TamjidTaha sorry I didn't provide it in the beginning but I didn't think of it before :) Glad it finally solved the issue.

Comment: I will be highly obliged if you could assist me in solving this problem. Please note that I have two accounts at stackoverflow - one using University mail and another one is personal mail which are permitted here. The link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63857503/how-to-attach-a-detail-sheet-as-pdf-or-excel-from-a-pivot-table-using-google-app

Comment: @TamjidTaha check my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `requireValueInList` use `requireValueInRange`. This implies that you should add the values in the list to a range.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requireValueInRange(Range)
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requirevalueinrangerange,-showdropdown

Comment: It is not working. I changed the code as var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(listToApply, false).build();